# how to grep multiple line start with a pattern into a single line using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, grep

What I'm trying to do is I would like to add multiple lines start with a pattern into a single line for example

test.txt contains

```
name: test1
role: manager
mail: test1@mail.com
name:test2
role: analyst
name:test3
```

I would like to `grep` start from "name" and end at "name" but not all "name" will end with "mail" some is without "mail"

desired output:

```
name: test1 role: manager mail: test1@mail.com
name:test2 role: analyst
name:test3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right tool for this is `awk`.  I am not sure this could be done with `grep`

```
awk '{printf (/^name/?RS:FS)"%s",$0}' test.txt

name: test1 role: manager mail: test1@mail.com
name:test2 role: analyst
name:test3
```

---

A `gnu awk` version (due to multiple characters in Record Separator)

```
awk 'NF{$1=$1;print RS,$0}' RS="name:" test.txt
name: test1 role: manager mail: test1@mail.com
name: test2 role: analyst
name: test3
```

Comment: YW, added a `gnu awk` version